# How are classes implemented internally in C++?

Tags: c++, class

I tried googling it, but didn't find any result. Is the implementation similar to the class hack in C using struct of function pointers and data? Or is it implemented in some another form?

Comment: The standard doesn't specify how it is to be implemented. Only how the implementation should behave. For a (old) read on some popular methods read "inside the c++ object model"

Comment: It al depends which compiler you're talking about, but see [Lippman, *The C++ Object Model*](http://www.amazon.com/Inside-Object-Model-Stanley-Lippman/dp/0201834545) for the general idea.

Comment: One part of C++ that is different than C is how it usually mangles the names of functions to allow for operator overloading by infusing the type into the name itself as its identifier. I'd imagine that a C++ class implementation would need to touch on this. 

C++ also needs some sort of exception and virtual function support, vtables, perhaps?

Comment: @EJP thanks for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not written any c++ compilers, but the structure of a class should contain:

- base class(es) data part (containing all data for base classes of the class)
- class instance data part (containing all data for an instance of the class)
- virtual table pointer (if the class or it's bases have at least one virtual function)

Note: non-virtual functions are referenced statically, so they should not be bound to a class instance directly.

That said, each compiler probably implements this a bit differently.

**TLDR**: essentially yes, the implementation has to be similar to the class hack (but this should be transparent/irrelevant for developers).

**Edit**:

This post is mostly speculation, based on years of debugging with visual studio (very subjective), backed with some experience years ago, maintaining a project that had the class hack supporting inheritance, implemented in C (such experience is very subjective as well).

For an example, in Visual Studio 6, you could see that the virtual function table was allocated before the c++ implementation-specific data. That is, a class looked like this:

```
[vtbl][data]
^1    ^2
```

so if this was for (for example) `struct X { virtual ~X(); int i; }`, then writing:

```
X a;
X *p = &a;
```

would create something similar to this:

```
[ptr + 1] -> any other virtual functions
[ptr + 0] -> X::~X
^x

[^x][data]
^1  ^2
    ^p = ^2;
```

with `^1` being where the operating system would allocate memory (and the vtbl would be filled in within the implementation of `new`), then the offset to user data (`vtbl + sizeof (vtbl)`) would be returned to the client code, as the address of the class. I don't know if this is still the case.

Comment: So if one makes a class with 50 member functions, there are 50 pointers created? I assume class hack is a struct of pointers to functions.

Comment: @rozina but only in the vtable and only for `virtual` functions!

Comment: @BeyelerStudios So it is not similar to the class hack :)

Comment: @rozina I have no idea what your class hack entails :)

Comment: @rozina, the class hack (as far as I have worked with it) involves manually maintaining a structure coupled with a function pointer table. Outside of the difference that, in C++ a class will only have a vtbl if it's parents have virtual functions, the two are the same.

Comment: @YSC, my post is mostly speculation, based on years of debugging with visual studio (very subjective), backed with some experience years ago, maintaining a project that had the class hack supporting inheritance, implemented in C (such experienc is very subjective as well).

Comment: @rozina, if one makes a class with 50 member function, they would still only need one function table for it (with 50 entries within), and each instance would need a pointer to reference this table (the same table). Then again, if I made a class with 50 virtual methods, I would probably also need counseling.

Comment: @utnapistim it's a good thing to know and gives value to your input. Why don't you edit your answer and get my upvote?

Comment: I didn't ask about virtual member functions, but regular ones. Imo that is a big difference from the C class implementation.

Comment: @rozina, in the class hack, nobody forces you to keep pointers to functions in the structure, if they require no virtual behavior. you could write `struct X { ... };`, then add an external `void X_add(X*p, /* data here */);` and then use the external `add` correctly, without keeping it in a function table. The function table would only be used to cover implementation virtualization.

Comment: You are right. It really is quite similar :) Thank you.

Comment: The vtable is filed in by the compiler and linker, not by the implementation of `new`, and each object contains a *pointer* to the vtable, not the vtable itself: there's only one of those per class. `(vtable+sizeof vtable)` is therefore incorrect, indeed meaningless. A class has a vtable if it or any of its parents have virtual functions or RTTI.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, normally (or at least sometimes) it would be implemented in a way that you can make it compatible with a "C-hack", but the details differs from compiler to compiler.

This becomes quite natural for a few reasons:

- C is/was designed to allow for low-level programming which would suggest that all data-types available on the processor would be available to a C implementation as well.
- The implementations of C/C++ are often bundled into the same product, which will result in a lot of shared code, the fundamental data types used in C++ could therefore easily be done available in C.
- The data types required for the class layout are basically the already present types of C/C++ language.

Basically, it's "easy" to implement C++ in a way that the class layout could be described in the accompanying C implementation, but also it's "harder" not to do it.

As a simple case of GCC layout we can consider a class with virtual methods (if it has no virtual method it would be a plain struct layoutwise). The layout will then start with the virtual table pointer which points to an array of words/pointers (containing both function pointers, pointer to the `type_info` node, and some other useful information). Then follows the members as if it were a normal struct.

When inheriting it's similar, it starts with the layout of the base class (natural since the pointer to the derived class should be easy to cast to a pointer of the base class) except now the virtual table pointer points to the virtual table of the derived class (which by the way has the same layout as the base class except it may have additional elements corresponding to new virtual methods introduced in the derived class - here to a pointer to the virtual table of the derived class can function as the virtual table of the base class).

In C this would look something like:

```
struct class_layout {
     void **__vptr;

     /* 
     base data members as they appear in the C++ definitions,
     (given they have fundamental types)
      */

     /*
      additional data members introduced in the derived class
     */
};
```

It would be tempting to define `__vptr` as a pointer to a `struct` that contains the function pointers, it would work fine except it would not be that compatible with how GCC does it. The detail is that there are entries in the virtual table at negative indices as well (probably for historical reasons).

Then there are some cases that require special care: A base class that doesn't have virtual methods for example would (almost) require that there is no virtual table pointer in the base class. The case of virtual inheritance would require a pointer to the base class object.

Comment: @YSC What citation do you need?

Comment: Where do you get those informations from?

Comment: @YSC For how GCC implements it is the source, for how MSVC implements it is by reverse engineering.

Comment: So you did read the GCC source code and reverse engineered MSVC. I'm impressed!

Comment: @YSC Yes, made GCC produce code compatible with MSVC libraries...

Comment: *That* is a citation! Please edit your post so I can upvote it... unless this production code has nothing in relation with how GCC handles C++ classes.

Comment: @YSC if you have something useful to say, post your own answer

Comment: @M.M I have, look, I've encouraged a user to improve its answer.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the answer would be "yes", since that is the most straightforward way. It is *by no means* guaranteed, however. The standard doesn't say what the compiler must do, it merely says what must happen under given conditions.

In the easiest, trivial case, a `class` is just the same as a `struct` where members default to `private`. Since you are unable to do anything with that `struct` (everything is private, no public members, no constructor), it's kind of pointless.

In the next easiest case, the `class` will also have member functions, including constructors and destructors.
Member functions covertly have a different calling convention since an implicit `this` pointer is passed on, but other than that they are just plain normal functions. Typically, the compiler will mangle the names into something like `_ZN12thenamespace9classname10membernameEv` where each of the "magic" letters and numbers has a clear, compiler-dependent meaning (I've tried to get a correctly mangled name in GCC's mangling scheme together, doing that by hand is a bit tedious).
The compiler will also call constructors and destructors on its own behalf when an object is created and destroyed. Other than that, these are basically "plain normal functions", too (with very few extra quirks that we will ignore here).

Then, there may be virtual functions. For that to work, typically, a pointer to a global table of function pointers is added in front of the data portion of the structure (one pointer per object, but only a single table globally for all objects of that type).
Again, like mangling, this is an implementation detail, not something that the standard requires (practically, that's how it's done virtually everywhere though).

In the most complicated case, several virtual function pointers are added, and the compiler secretly adjusts an object's pointer accordingly to what the current object's type is (casting a pointer may indeed give a different address, too). That ensures that the "correct" virtual function is called without you having to know.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this presentation interesting and useful:
http://www.hexblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/Recon-2011-Skochinsky.pdf

In general, a non-virtual class is laid out more or less as it would be in C.

A virtual class must store a virtual function table, a pointer to run time type info and an 'offset' so the data can be found in an arbitrarily complex derived class.

These three objects are folded into the virtual function table.